# Joomla CSS Browser/Server Cache Issue

Tags: css, joomla

I need to bring back an element that I temporarily removed from the module.css file in my customized Joomla template. I removed a search ZooFilter add-on CSS element that should be at the top of the page. I want it to look something like this:

[image]

I made an edit to the CSS of this site over two days ago and it still has not been updated. That file is stored on a A2 hosting (I "believe") CloudFlare Enabled server (which I do not have access to from my employer).

The file is located [here](http://www.mannachurch.org/manna2012/smallgroups/templates/manna-small-groups/warp/css/modules.css). And the webpage I'm talking about is [here](http://www.mannachurch.org/manna2012/smallgroups/).

The code I want removed is simply

```
.module {visibility:hidden!important;}
```

and the code I need added is

```
#searchbox-63 {visibility:hidden !important;}
```

These above edits show perfectly fine in real time in my Joomla dashboard CSS editor in the appropriate module.css file, but alas, after clearing the template cache, browser cache, expired cache. The element still remains hidden.

Another funny thing is that on my work computer (work network), the element remains hidden, but on my home computer(home network), it shows the element I want fine (it provides an extra search nav, but I think I did that by accidentally adding a custom mod by accident)!!! Can I justify this as CloudFlare server-end cache (or some CDN) issues?

Answer (score 1):

When viewing source of "http://www.mannachurch.org/manna2012/smallgroups/", there is no link to the stylesheet "module.css", only the plural, "modules.css".

Also, the file you linked to is here:

```
/manna2012/smallgroups/templates/manna-small-groups/warp/css/modules.css
```

Yet the 'modules.css' file referenced in the source code is somewhere else:

```
/manna2012/smallgroups/templates/manna-small-groups/styles/wide/css/modules.css
```

Are you sure your file paths are all correct?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. The server that this site was hosted on  was hosted ohad CloudFlare. I did have access to that server, hence I did not know that that was activated. The above comment was right, the file was named `modules.css` not `module.css` However the file path was correct.

In addition, my local network server is having DNS issues, hence adding to the difficulty (and pull-your-hair-out frustration).